# How to get checkbox value and send that to backend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nodes, ejs

This is front end,

```
<div class="uk-width-1-4 ">
   <table class="uk-table uk-table-striped uk-table-hover" id="tabledata">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox"  ></th>
            <th>Site ID</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <input type="checkbox" id="chkall"  value="<%= d.siteid%>">
            </td>
            <td><%=d.siteid%></td>
         </tr>
         <%  });
            } %>         
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

This is backend,

```
   var user_id=req.query.user_id; 
   var siteid=req.query.chkall;
   console.log("chkall =="+siteid);
    sql="UPDATE site SET userid='"+user_id+"' WHERE siteid IN('"+siteid+"')";
  }
  getSQLData(sql, function(resultsets){
      console.log("user...sql"+sql);
       userresults = resultsets;
  });
```

Comment: On which action you want to communicate with the backend ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").val();
```

Hope will help you.

Comment: you can use this value in variable and send by ajax

Comment: I used like this sir,                                                                                           var chkall = document.getElementById("chkall").value;
     console.log("x val is=="+chkall);

Comment: var x = document.getElementById("chkall").value;  you have to use like this in script tag

Comment: It is getting only first row value sir,i want to get value which has been checked but m not getting sir

Comment: do you want send the checked value to db?

Comment: I want to send checked siteid values to backend and i want to use that checked values in  update query

Comment: then you have to use ajax to send the id to update the records

Comment: can you please give me some idea?

Comment: var x = document.getElementById("chkall").value; $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
     url: "updatepage.php",
     data:"id="+id,
     success: function() {
        alert("Success Input");
     }

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing form submit, and if the check-box un-checked the false value will not go to the back-end. You should have some hidden value if check box un-checked.

If it is ajax call, you can get checkbox value as like below

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").val();

or 

$("#checkboxid").val();
```

Comment: by default it is getting first row value if it unchecked also.

Comment: i tried in both way but by default it is taking first row value sir, 1) var chkall = document.getElementById("chkall").value; 2) $("input[type='checkbox']").val();     For both its showing same

Comment: Check box name should be an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you submit form then write name tag. And if you send data from ajax then get value by element id then send to server.

Comment: by default it is getting first row value if it unchecked also

Comment: i tried in both way but by default it is taking first row value sir, 1) var chkall = document.getElementById("chkall").value; 2) $("input[type='checkbox']").val(); For both its showing same

Comment: It is not taking other row values if checked also.

Comment: Please make array of name for check box. like name="myname[]"

Answer (score 0):

You do like this..

```
var chk = document.getElementById(checkboxid).checked;

if (chk == true) {   
    var chkval=$("#checkboxid").val();
}
```

If you have in list then do loop and add to a global variable and use that variable.

Comment: i have 100 siteid's, frontend i m displaying that all siteid's , if i select perticular siteid checkbox then then i want to retrieve that perticular siteid value and through ajax i m passing that perticular checkbox siteid to backend

Comment: we can do both the ways, onclick call ajax function and update your data base it will be very fast ,if you want i will send the code example.. other wise i will edit the code to fetch the checked id's...

Answer (score 0):

//check box

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkpermission" runat="server" onclick="checking(this.id);" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("permission")) %>' />

<script type="text/javascript">
        function checking(id) {
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblresponce').val('');
            if (id) {
                ids = id.split('_');
                var chkval = document.getElementById(id).checked;
                var TitleId = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdpermissions_" + ids[3] + "_hdntitleid"; //here i am getting the value from the grid

                var pagePath = window.location.pathname;
                var param = JSON.stringify({ "TitleId": itleId,"chkval":chkval });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: pagePath + "/updatevalue",
                    data: param,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data != null) {
                            var result = data.d;
                            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblresponce').text('Updated successfully');

                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                        alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                        alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                    }
                });
            }


        }
    </script>
```

in the back end code

```
[WebMethod]
    public static Boolean updatevalue( string TitleId,  string chkval)
    {
       Boolean flag = false;
        if ( TitleId != "" &&  chkval !="")
        {
          //Update your your query here with single id...

flag=true;
// return flag if updated
        }



        return flag;
    }
```

I hope it works in your case.